# Parameter optional from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, controller, option-type

I have an ActionResult with 3 parameters, but in the moment when y redirect from the other ActionResult, throw an error for the 3 parameters are null.

```
     pubblic ActionResult Comentar()
     {
          return Redirect("GeneralTop");
     }

[HttpGet]
     public ActionResult GeneralTop(string name, int opcion, int id)
     {
             My code
     }
```

when i redirect from Comentar, doesn´t work the view. Help pls? (engine aspx)

Comment: You can make the parameters optional by ussing nullable types (e.g. `int? opcion`)

Comment: but if i do that, throw the next error in the variables that use opcion, can´t convert int? into int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     pubblic ActionResult Comentar()
     {
          return RedirectToAction("GeneralTop",new {name:"test",option:4,id:3});
     }
```

Try the above

If you want the parameters to be optional you should use nullable types.

Comment: are you sure the syntax is right? because dont let me put like this way

Comment: work but you forgot the new {name:"test",option:4,id:3}, thanks a lot ;)